# Access query expression returns incorrect

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on a query that pulls a date from another query, I have my reasons for the nesting. The problem I'm facing is that there is a field that is called DueDate.

My SQL is

```
SELECT DueDate 
FROM qryDueDates
WHERE DueDates <= DateAdd("d",60,Date())
```

The data causing the issue is when it equals something like "1/25/2019", "11/19/2019" or any date in 2019.

## **Goal**

I need to limit the results to show dates that are expired or expiring within 60 days or less.

[image: Results]

I'm trying to prepare the dataset for the conditional formatting.

[image: Report]

Comment: If I'm not being a bit dim, 1/25/2019 is more than 60 day away so wouldn't show up? As is 11/19/2019 ? In fact at the time of writing 3-Oct-2017 any date even in 2018 would be more than 60 days away?

Comment: @Minty That's my point. It shouldn't show up but they do.

Comment: Just noticed you are selecting duedate and the where clause is referring to duedates (extra S on the end)? Also - Since your edit - I notice you have a field value of "excluded", this is not possible in a date field therefore you aren't comparing dates with dates, you are comparing text. So I think @Rai is on the right track.  Is this in SQL or Access?

Comment: You wrote your dates within quotes. That is confusing. Are they dates or text ? Dates should be surrounded by #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the original query was screwing it up. I moved the query into the main one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you can put your nested sub-query in your post that may give better picture, and if you can mention what is the error you are getting that may also help. Since you mentioned that you are getting error only when sub-query returns certain dates, I would suggest that cast your sub-query result to DATE if you have not already done.

Below is my attempt to help you with limited information I could extract from your post.  I have used some of MS-SQL function below, please replace with your DB specific function.

```
SELECT myDates.* FROM (select COLUMN_NAME DueDates from TABLE_NAME) as myDates WHERE myDates.DueDates <= DateAdd("d",60, GETDATE())
```